# How to scrape Traditional Chinese text with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup to grab Chinese text from this website.

Sometimes it works:

```
http://www.fashionguide.com.tw/Beauty/08/MsgL.asp?LinkTo=TopicL&TopicNum=13976&Absolute=1
Tsaio上山採藥 輕油水感全效UV防曬精華
```

Sometimes it doesn't work:

```
http://www.fashionguide.com.tw/Beauty/08/MsgL.asp?LinkTo=TopicL&TopicNum=13996&Absolute=1
MAYBELLINE´A¤ñµY ³z¥Õ¼á²bªø®Ä¢ã¢ä¯»»æ
```

When I tried encoding to utf-8 with:

```
title1 = tds.find("span",attrs={"class": "style1", "itemprop": "brand"})
title2 = tds.find("span",attrs={"class": "style1", "itemprop": "name"})
print ((title1.text + title2.text).encode('utf-8'))
```

I get:

```
b'MAYBELLINE\xc2\xb4A\xc2\xa4\xc3\xb1\xc2\xb5Y \xc2\xb3z\xc2\xa5\xc3\x95\xc2\xbc\xc3\xa1\xc2\xb2b\xc2\xaa\xc3\xb8\xc2\xae\xc3\x84\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa3\xc2\xa2\xc3\xa4\xc2\xaf\xc2\xbb\xc2\xbb\xc3\xa6'
```

What can I do to get the correct Chinese text?

**Edit:**
I just switched to python3, so I may have made some mistakes. This is how I'm grabbing the html:

```
contentb = urllib.request.urlopen(urlb).read()
soupb = BeautifulSoup(contentb)
```

Comment: How did you *load* the HTML? Did you use `urllib.request`, `requests`, another library? Did you load the response body straight into BeautifulSoup or did you also inspect the response headers?

Comment: Sometimes the mojibake is caused by the encoding being detected as something else (often Latin-1). It can help if you try to `encode()` first as that and then `decode()` utf-8.

Comment: I used urllib.request and put the results into soupb. edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly noticed, default BS parser doesn't work in this case. Also explicitly using Big5 (charset declared in your html).

But you should get your job done using lxml + BeautifulSoup, paying attention in initializing your soup with bytes, not unicode.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.content

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = '?'.join(['http://www.fashionguide.com.tw/Beauty/08/MsgL.asp',
                     'LinkTo=TopicL&TopicNum={topic}&Absolute=1'])
topics = [13976, 13996, ]

for t in topics:
    url = base_url.format(topic=t)
    page_content = requests.get(url).content  # returns bytes
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'lxml')
    title1 = soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "style1", "itemprop": "brand"})
    title2 = soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "style1", "itemprop": "name"})
    print(title1.text + title2.text)
```

And here is the same solution using xpath, which I prefer :-)

```
from lxml import html
import requests

base_url = '?'.join(['http://www.fashionguide.com.tw/Beauty/08/MsgL.asp',
                     'LinkTo=TopicL&TopicNum={topic}&Absolute=1'])
topics = [13976, 13996, ]

xp1 = "//*[@itemprop='brand']/text()"
xp2 = "//*[@itemprop='brand']/following-sibling::span[1]/text()"

for t in topics:
    url = base_url.format(topic=t)
    page_content = requests.get(url).content
    tree = html.fromstring(page_content)
    title1 = tree.xpath(xp1)  # returns a list!
    title2 = tree.xpath(xp2)
    title = " ".join(title1 + title2)
    print(title)
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, thanks! I'll look more into xpath and see what I can do.